# jQuery clone infinite times?

Tags: jquery, clone, infinite

The way jQuery's `.clone()` seems to work, once you insert a cloned object somewhere, you cannot insert it again another time without re-cloning the original object. For example, if you do this:

```
var cloned = $('#elem1').clone();
$('#elem2').after(cloned);
$('#elem2').after(cloned);
```

Only one copy of `elem1` will get copied and the second `after` call would have done nothing.

Is there a way to not "clear the clipboard" after using a cloned object? Right now I am making do by cloning the object again before inserting it somewhere. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two lines just move the same jQuery set of elements twice. If you want a new copy yes you have to clone it again. `after()` doesn't clone anything. It just moves content around. `clone()` in this case is what's creating the content.

```
var cloned = $('#elem1').clone();
$('#elem2').after(cloned);
cloned = $('#elem1').clone();
$('#elem2').after(cloned);
```

Also you should change or remove the ID attribute when you do that:

```
var cloned = $('#elem1').clone().removeAttr("id");
$('#elem2').after(cloned);
cloned = $('#elem1').clone().removeAttr("id");
$('#elem2').after(cloned);
```

as duplicate IDs technically aren't allowed so behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I just used ID selectors as examples - should have been more careful.

Comment: Not a jquery expert; is the second search required? Could you do, e.g., `cloned = cloned.clone()` instead of `cloned = $('#elem1').clone()` on the third line?

Comment: @danielWagner That is not a good idea, unless your cloned element was empty (which shouldn't be, because then you should use a loop to create these elements). Otherwise you will be cloning any dynamically added input already inserted in your 'cloned' variable ;)