# jQuery click event only works once (but fires always!)

Tags: jquery

Please help a jQuery newby with the following. I have a form and I'm trying to add successive chunks of form fields when an #addMore button is clicked. With the help of this board, I have that working now. But it only works once. I've whittled things down to a minimal case:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Reserves Form</title>
<script src="../jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var chunk = $('.content').clone(true);
 $('#addMore').live('click', function() {
     alert('debug!');
     $('#container').append(chunk);
 });    
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="container">
<p class="content">lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
</div>
<button type="button" id="addMore">Add Another Paragraph</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page and click the button, I see the debugging alert and then a clone of the "content" paragraph appears as expected. When I click the button again, I get the alert, but not the new paragraph. Why would one response to the click work, but not the other? And how can I get them both to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the same object again and again to the same container so you won't see any difference as if it is not doing anything.

Try this which will clone the first `.content` element inside the click handler and append it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#addMore').live('click', function() {
       alert('debug!');
       $('#container').append($('.content:first').clone(true));
   });    
});
```

Alternatively you can try this which will append html string instead of cloned object. In this approach the clone is used only once because string appending can be done any number of times so it is better than previous approach.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var content = $('<div />').append($('.content').clone(true)).html();

   $('#addMore').live('click', function() {
       alert('debug!');
       $('#container').append(content);
   });    

});
```

Answer (score 4):

put the `chunk = $('.content').clone(true);` inside the click event to be like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#addMore').live('click', function() {
    var chunk = $('.content').clone(true);
     alert('debug!');
     $('#container').append(chunk);
 });    
});
```

and something else not related to your question: do you really want to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)?

Comment: Good Answer, +1. Another problem I noticed is that with the selector used in the question all elements with the class .content will be duplicated for every click. So first click adds 1, second click adds two ...

Comment: Oops! I should be using "on". sorry

Comment: probably $('.content').last().clone(true);

Answer (score 0):

A [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264167/jquery-clone-infinite-times) has already been asked.  You need to clone the element every time your handler is executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#addMore').live('click', function() {
     var chunk = $('.content').clone(true);
     alert('debug!');
     $('#container').append(chunk);
 });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to occur every time, you need to clone the paragraph inside of your live handler. Your script is appending a one-time clone (cached) copy of that paragraph. Move the clone statement into your click handler for expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You're only cloning once. After that first assignment you are just referring to the cloned element, thus it's just moving it from where it is to where you want it to be. You can fix it by making chunk a function that returns the cloned element:

```
var chunk = function() {
   return $('.content').clone(true);
}
```